# eval inline mongodb replica set config

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I can setup mongodb replica set in the following way:

```
mongo --port 27020 < config.js
```

where `config.js` is javascript configuration file:

```
    config = {
    _id: "rsRunly",
    members: [{
        _id: 0,
        host: "o502:27018"
    }, {
        _id: 1,
        host: "o502:27019"
    }, {
        _id: 3,
        host: "o502:27021"
    }]
};
rs.initiate(config);
rs.status();
```

But cannot do it inline:

```
mongo --port 27020 < 'config = {_id: "rsRunly", members: [ {_id: 0, host: "o502:#27020"}, {_id: 1, host: "o502:27019"}, {_id: 3, host: "o502:27021"}]}; rs.initiate(config); rs.status();';
```

Got error:

```
2014-08-05T06:48:34.218-0400 SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier at (connect)
exception: connect failed
```

I tried using `--eval`

```
mongo --port 27020  --eval   'config = {_id: "rsRunly", members: [ {_id: 0, host: "o502:27020"}, {_id: 1, host: "o502:27019"}, {_id: 3, host: "o502:27021"}]}; rs.initiate(config); rs.status();'
```

And it gives me output:

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.3
connecting to: 127.0.0.1:27020/test
[object Object]
```

But replica set is not created.

**Why** do I need create replica set config inline?
Because I am creating one big `sh` file where at first all mongo nodes are started and then start replica set. And I use bash variables there like `$port1`, `$port2`, `$port3` to keep bash code dry. So if I would use `config.js` instead of inline config I must edit port number 2 times in my `sh` file and in `config.js` file.

So **how to initiate replica set not in `config.js`** file but using bash command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem here is that the replica set `.initiate()` does not "immediately" start the replica set. There is a delay while each member retrieves the configuration and enters it's own startup phase.

As such you need to "wait" for the set to move into a ready state. The best way to do this is periodically test the `rs.status()` response:

> mongo --port 30000 --eval 'var config = { _id: "rs0", members: [ { _id: 0, host: "localhost:30000" }, { _id: 1, host: "localhost:30001" }, { _id: 3, host: "localhost:30002" } ] }; rs.initiate( config ); while (rs.status().startupStatus || (rs.status().hasOwnProperty("myState") && rs.status().myState != 1)) { printjson( rs.status() ); sleep(1000); }; printjson( rs.status() );'

The `.startupStatus` field will be present in the response until a reasonable state is reached. So basically you otherwise loop. That's how this works and will return the full status when complete.

And the replica set is only really available when there is a PRIMARY, but you might also want to inspect that structure to confirm the startup states of the other members as well.

You should look into the startup values for this in order to check for errors when you are scripting. Also consider connection errors unless you have otherwise implemented waits and checks for that all the processes are running.